Creating a single paragraph with loop Velocity
I have multiple variables in a list and I want to create a single paragraph for all of them that share the same property of what we'll call class.requirement for example's sake. I want to make a paragraph that's like:
$item1.text$item2.text$item5.text 

etc assuming items 1, 2, and 5 share the requirement and 3 and 4 do not.
I currently have a for loop that can access each of the items with the requirements and print them out, but it is in multiple paragraphs e.g.
$item1.text
$item2.text
$item5.text

etc.
Is there any way to make it into one line?
